# sqlpackage table list

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to run sqlpackage from powershell with a dynamic list of tables but am getting an error putting the list of tables into a var.  I need to put the table list into a var because it is going to be generated dynamically.

The following code works just fine:

```
.\sqlpackage.exe `
    /a:Export `
    /scs:"Data Source=$($ServerName);Initial Catalog=$($SourceDbName);User ID=my_user;Password=my_password" `
    /tf:$BacPacFileName `
    /p:TableData=[dbo].[QRTZ_CALENDARS] /p:TableData=[dbo].[QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE]
```

However, when I put the list of tables in a var, it fails:

```
$tableList = "/p:TableData=[dbo].[QRTZ_CALENDARS] /p:TableData=[dbo].[QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE]"

.\sqlpackage.exe `
    /a:Export `
    /scs:"Data Source=$($ServerName);Initial Catalog=$($SourceDbName);User ID=my_user;Password=my_password" `
    /tf:$BacPacFileName `
    $($tableList)
```

Error text:

```
.\sqlpackage.exe : Argument 'TableData' has an invalid value:
'[dbo].[QRTZ_CALENDARS] /p:TableData=[dbo].[QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE]'.
Table to extract data from must be specified using the two-part table
name format: schema_name.table_identifier.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\sqlpackage.exe `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Argument 'T...ble_identifier.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError  Incorrect syntax near /.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `$tableList` is passed as a *single argument*, not a list of arguments. What you actually want to do here is called [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0):

```cs
$cs = "Data Source=${ServerName};Initial Catalog=${SourceDbName};" +
      'User ID=my_user;Password=my_password'

$params = '/a:Export',
          "/scs:`"${cs}`"",
          "/tf:${BacPacFileName}",
          '/p:TableData=[dbo].[QRTZ_CALENDARS]',
          '/p:TableData=[dbo].[QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE]'

.\sqlpackage.exe @params
```